# Issue with simple if elif statement within a for loop in Django/Webapp2

Tags: django, django-templates, webapp2

I am trying to use a relatively simple if elif statement within a for loop, but it seems to throw an error. This is the syntax that I am using

```
{% for ruleset in rulesets %}
<!-- some simple html / template tags come here -->
{% for rule in rules %}
  {% if rule.0 = ruleset.0 and rule.2 = 1 %}
    {{ rule.1 }}: {{ rule.3 }} out of {{ rule.4 }} points above {{ rule.5 }} sigma
  {% elif rule.0 = ruleset.0 and rule.2 = 2 %}
    {{ rule.1 }}: {{ rule.3 }} out of {{ rule.4 }} points below {{ rule.5 }} sigma
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

There are a few more rules that I will want to incorporate, so I can't just use the else tag.

The error I am getting is:
TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag: 'elif', expected 'else' or 'endif'

Any suggestions as to how to solve this? I was using nested if clauses at some point too, but was getting similar errors.

Comment: `elif` is supported. but do note that your `=` condition is supposed to be `==`. or you can use the `ifequal` template tag instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`elif` is supported since django 1.4

it may be that you are using an older version of django.

see my comment regarding the `=` sign that is supposed to be `==` to evaluate to True or False as expected. Or you can use the `ifequal` template tag instead.

Comment: That makes sense. I am actually using WebApp2, but was always using the Django documentation as it is better. Turns out that WebApp2 doesn't seem to support elif.

Answer (score 1):

The `elif` statement was added to Django in version 1.4 ([Django 1.4 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#minor-features)).

If you are using an older Django version you will either have to upgrade to a newer version or use nested if/else statements.